# Which version of Rogue Galaxy (PS2) is the one that doesn't freeze?

Tags: ps2

I want to get this game, for my Ps2, but i herd somewhere people saying that this game could freeze at the middle of the adventure, is this true? it is the EUR, USA or JAP version the one with this problem? So i can avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I read on multiple forums, it seems to be an issue around chapter 7. When you get to a specific part of the game in chapter 7, the game changes over from reading the first layer to the second layer on the Dual Layer disk.   As long as you have a legal copy of this, the disk is not heavily scratched, and your disk reader is healthy on your PS2, you should be fine.